# My PC Speakers/Sub Stopped working

Tags: audio, speakers

I have a simple setup 2 speakers and a sub. Just recently the volume control led wouldn't show up and when i tried playing music through my computer nothing happened.  The only way i can play music is if i plug headphones directly into the onboard sound input. What could be the reason for this and do i need a new sub/power cable or is there a quick fix?

Creative Inspire T700
Speakers, power etc plug directly into the sub.
Cannot plug them into my onboard sound.

Comment: What's your operating system, and which kind of speakers do you have? How do you connect them to your computer? Can you test the speakers on another device (e.g. mobile phone, iPod, etc.)? Please [edit] and tell us more.

Comment: Do any lights on the speakers go on? have you tried a different outlet or a different power cord? If you can verify the power is fine, then do what slhck suggested, test them on another device.

Comment: They dont light neither does the volume control thing.

Comment: Sounds like a power issue. If they have a removable power cable, try swapping it out, try other outlets/power strips.